# SQL nested Select with IPv4/IPv6

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ipv6, ipv4

Using the below MSSQL Select statement works fine when an IPv4 address is returned but when an IPv6 address is found in the DB the script errors with:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Script:

```
select [column 3]
from [IPs]
where [dbo].[IP2INT]
    (
        RIGHT(
            LEFT(
                [IPBan_Log],
                CHARINDEX(',', [IP_Log]) - 1
            ),
            LEN(
                LEFT(
                    [IP_Log],
                    CHARINDEX(',', [IP_Log]) - 1
                )
            ) - CHARINDEX('ss', [IP_Log]) - 2
        )
    ) between [Column 0] and [Column 1]
)
```

Any ideas how I can change the script to handle IPv6 (fe80::d474:f998:3980:360d) as well as IPv4 (91.204.2121.163)?

Our custom function:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER function [dbo].[IP2INT](@ipAddress varchar(20)) 
RETURNS bigint 
AS 
BEGIN 

DECLARE @FirstDot int, @SecondDot int, @ThirdDot int, 
        @FirstOctet varchar(3), @SecondOctet varchar(3), 
        @ThirdOctet varchar(3), @FourthOctet varchar(3), 
        @Result bigint 

    SET @FirstDot = CHARINDEX('.', @ipAddress) 
    SET @SecondDot = CHARINDEX('.', @ipAddress, @FirstDot + 1) 
    SET @ThirdDot = CHARINDEX('.', @ipAddress, @SecondDot + 1) 

    SET @FirstOctet = SUBSTRING(@ipAddress, 1, @FirstDot - 1) 
    SET @SecondOctet = SUBSTRING(@ipAddress, @FirstDot + 1, @SecondDot - @FirstDot - 1) 
    SET @ThirdOctet = SUBSTRING(@ipAddress, @SecondDot + 1, @ThirdDot - @SecondDot - 1) 
    SET @FourthOctet = SUBSTRING(@ipAddress, @ThirdDot + 1, 3) 

    SET @Result = 16777216 * CAST(@FirstOctet as bigint) + 
                  65536    * CAST(@SecondOctet as bigint) + 
                  256      * CAST(@ThirdOctet as bigint) + 
                             CAST(@FourthOctet as bigint) 
    RETURN(@Result); 


END
```

Comment: Can you please explain the need of that extra last parenthesis, please?

Comment: This Select is nested in another Select and so I copied the last one but not the first one - sorry...

Comment: You'll have to come up with some sort of funky test to see if any given value is IPv4 or IPv6.  Maybe check to see if it contains a colon or not?

Comment: One problem that you're going to have right off the bat is that an IPv6 value is 128 bits and will not fit into a `BIGINT` which only has 64 bits.

Comment: That function smells horrible. But that's a matter for another day. The root problem here is that IPv4 and IPv6 have completely different formats, and you have a much bigger job ahead of you than you realize. None of the code you've posted above is going to work with IPv6 at all.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see a native ip2int function documented for tsql, so I assume you have your own implementation, which is not IPv6 compatible and just returns NULL or similar on any address it cannot parse (like IPv6). If you would provide your implementation one could have a look.